# JavaScript HTML/DOM updates stuck, until all Ajax calls are finished. (in Chrome/Safari)

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, dom, safari

Using JavaScript. I try to call about 50-100 HTTP/Ajax Request (in Loop) while updating HTML-DOM-Elements based on AJAX/HTTP response in realtime, In Firefox this works great!

The problem I challenge, is that Chrome/Safari(and Opera), don't update the HTML page until the loop of all 100 request is ended. 
Even GIF animations like 'prealoaders' are stuck-ed.

Any clue? or tip?

### I already tried :

HTTP REQUEST LIBS/functions:

- Plain JavaScript XMLHttpRequest()
- JQuery $.ajax()

HTML/DOM starting of the Loop on document load:

- $(window).bind("load", function()
- document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function()

PROGRAMING WORKFLOW:

- Starting LOOP with 100 iterations
- Starting update functions N-times separately. (without loop)
- I also tried to wait N milliseconds in loop and while calling functions.

```
function update_100_items_in_html_by_ajax(){

    var item_list='1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,XX,YY,Z'.split(',');

    for (item_id in item_list) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "/item_id.php?id="+item_id, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById('item_id_'+item_id).innerHTMLxmlhttp.responseText;
        };

    };

};
```

## ... and I call the JavaScript from HTML like this...

```html
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        update_100_items_in_html_by_ajax();
    });
```

### Question I search...

How to non-block Browser and Update DOM in realtime? while making Javascript/Ajax calls?

THX. A lot.

Comment: Is your `ajax` call synchronous ?

Comment: Your are making sync calls, this means the browser keeps waiting till it's done, as you noticed, this is bad for performance.

Comment: I call HTTP/Ajax synchronous, waiting for the response. (the reason is I don't want to DDoS the web server with HTTP request). Anyway I need the full response to update DOM.

Anyway I don't think HTTP request causing this... If I do any LOOP() then Chrome and Safari is not updating/rendering DOM content.

Comment: Browsers generally don't reflow or repaint while JS is executing. So yes, it waits for all 100 requests to complete